# confusion with recursion flow in merge sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion

```
public class test {                                 
public static void main(String[] args){
    mergeSort(0, 4);        
}

public static void mergeSort(int low, int high){
    if(low < high){
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        mergeSort(low, mid);
        mergeSort(mid+1, high);
    }
  }
}
```

Im having some confusion when the program reaches `mergeSort(mid+1,high);`. When it does, `high = 1` and `low = 0;` So when `mergeSort(mid+1, high)` is called it passes through `mergeSort(0+1, 1)` So now `high = 1` and `low = 1` therefore the if statement fails, and goes to the end of the method.

What I find confusing is when after the if statement fails and jumps out of the method with `high = 1;` and `low = 1;`, the program jumps back to `mergeSort(mid+1, high);` and magically `low = 0;`, `mid = 1;`, and `high = 2;`. I am confused with how the program is flowing and why it is jumping all over the place.

Comment: Put debug point and check. It is best trick to checking code execution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not "jumping all over the place".
There is a pattern.

log base 2 of high-low calls are made to mergeSort(low, mid);
After these calls begin returning, mergeSort(mid+1, high); is called for each of them.

This call to mergeSort(mid+1, high) will than call mergeSort(low,mid) again.

in your example, the calls look like this:

```
mergeSort(0,4);
mergeSort(0,2);
mergeSort(0,1);
mergeSort(0,0);
mergeSort(1,1);
mergeSort(2,2);
mergeSort(3,4);
mergeSort(3,3);
mergeSort(4,4);
```